Is there any way to persist jpa entity which is joined by using left join on?
there are two JPA entities in my project.
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "review")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class ReviewJpaEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "review_id")
    private Long id;

    ... some codes ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reviewJpaEntity")
    private List<ComplaintJpaEntity> complaintJpaEntities = new ArrayList<>();

    ... some codes ...

}

@Getter
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "complaint")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class ComplaintJpaEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "complaint_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserJpaEntity userJpaEntity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "review_id")
    private ReviewJpaEntity reviewJpaEntity;

    ... some codes ...

}

Now, I want to find all reviewJpaEntities which each include the compliantJpaEntities that only matched with specific userId I gave.
The query in jpaRepository is like this.
@Query("select r "
        + "from ReviewJpaEntity r "
        + "left join r.complaintJpaEntities c on c.userJpaEntity.id = :userId"
List<ReviewJpaEntity> findAllWithComplaintByComplaintUserId(Long userId);

However, when I call the function "review.getComplaintJpaEntities()", the complaintJpaEntities show all complaints regardless of userId I gave.
Is there any way to persist jpa entity that is joined by using left join on?
I want like this
[
  {
    "reviewId": "2024100613323615587",
    "complaints": [
      {
        "id": "2024100613323615588"
        "userId": "2024100613323615589"
      }
    ]
  },{
    "reviewId": "2024100613323615590",
    "complaints": [
      {
        "id": "2024100613323615591"
        "userId": "2024100613323615589"
      }
    ]
  },{
    "reviewId": "2024100613323615590",
    "complaints": []
  }
]

I don't want like this
[
  {
    "reviewId": "2024100613323615587",
    "complaints": [
      {
        "id": "2024100613323615588"
        "userId": "2024100613323615589"
      }
    ]
  },{
    "reviewId": "2024100613323615590",
    "complaints": [
      {
        "id": "2024100613323615591"
        "userId": "2024100613323615589"
      },{
        "id": "2024100613323615591"
        "userId": "2024100613323615590"
      }
    ]
  },{
    "reviewId": "2024100613323615590",
    "complaints": [
      {
        "id": "2024100613323615591"
        "userId": "2024100613323615590"
      }
    ]
  }
]


Please add code for UserJpaEntity and if you use some DTOs / mapping classes add them too

Your question is imprecise; persist means save, and you are not actually asking to save something here are you?  The 'review' instance is a managed entity instance so review.getComplaintJpaEntities() is required by the JPA spec to return you the data as it is in the database, not your filtered query. If you want a filtered, partial list of complaint entities associated to a review, query for them directly. Otherwise caching could never reliably work, as who knows what view of the data is in the cache at any moment, and change tracking would be difficult for JPA
